# Bearer Token Auth - How to get SignIn User Value in controller ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, bearer-token, asp.net-core-identity

I tried a few ways to get the logged in user from inside the controller but it does not seem to be working. Here is one of the examples I tried. Most of the examples I saw was related to .NET Core 1.x. Is there a difference in the way to get the user from inside the controller in .NET Core 2.1? Following the examples I am constantly getting null for my user object. Thank you! :)

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    //For ASP.NET Identity Only | You can reuse this but replace dbname with your own database name
    private string GetRdsConnectionString()
    {
        string hostname = Configuration.GetValue<string>("RDS_HOSTNAME");
        string port = Configuration.GetValue<string>("RDS_PORT");
        string dbname = "ASPNETIdentityUser";
        string username = Configuration.GetValue<string>("RDS_USERNAME");
        string password = Configuration.GetValue<string>("RDS_PASSWORD");

        return $"Data Source={hostname},{port};Initial Catalog={dbname};User ID={username};Password={password};";
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        //Using RDS
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
        GetRdsConnectionString()));

        //This has been commented out and moved to Identity Hosting Startup
        //services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
        //    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        //    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.AllowAreas = true;
        options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Identity", "/Account/Manage");
        options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("Identity", "/Account/Logout");
    });

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = $"/Identity/Account/Login";
            options.LogoutPath = $"/Identity/Account/Logout";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = $"/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseAuthentication();


        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I should work the same way in ASP.NET Core 2.1. Could you provide more code? Especially how you set up authentication and login?

Comment: Also, does your controller inherit `Controller`?

Comment: The authentication and login is default Identity from Microsoft. Yes my controller inherits controller.

Comment: And is the user definitely logged in? `null` would look like user is actually not logged in

Comment: Try this - `this.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);`

Comment: Yes the user is definitely logged in. The page can only be accessed when the user is logged in.

Comment: I have played around with getting user in view-cshtml but this is the first time I'm trying out in the controller

Comment: Could you please also post the code of your `Startup.Configure` method?

Comment: Added the most important parts of startup.cs. Your example didn't work unfortunately

Comment: I don't think it's possible @TanvirArjel

Comment: Being logged in != an actual record existing in the `AspNetUsers` table. For example, if the user signs in with an external provider and your app does not explicitly force a user to be created, then there will only be a `UserLogin` record, not a `User` record. Attempting to get the `User`, thus, would return null.

Comment: I am using the normal Identity with all data saved to the Database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of traditional httpcontext you can use the base Controller class IClaimsPrincipal User property in ASP.Net Core action method provided UserManager is initialized in Controller Constructor and the User is signin. Like below

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(this.User);
```

In case of Bearer Token, get SignIn User by Name. Like below:

```
//Get userId
var userId = this.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
```

Comment: There is no difference between using `HttpContext.User` and `this.User` in the controller.

Comment: It doesn't work too. I expanded in debug and am able to see name under this.User, but user itself is still null

Comment: @zzdhxu edited my answer, probably you are using bearer token authentication.

Comment: Hmm this line got what I needed actually...           var userName = this.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
I was thinking of getting user before getting user.Id, but it seems like to userName itself is actually the userId! Thank you! I think the question and answer needs to be edited though...